# Does rename of page slugs create 301 redirects from old slug to new (same as for posts)?

Tags: permalinks, redirect, slug

Does rename of page slugs create 301 redirects from old slug to new (same as for posts)?

Starting a fresh install of wp `wordpress:4.9.4-php7.1` I'm trying to get automatic redirects for renamed page permalinks working.

1. Creating a page with permalink `/a`
2. Rename that page permalink to `/b`
3. I expect GET `/a` to return a 301 redirect to `/b`

Creating a post with slug `a` and then renaming it to `b` creates a 301 redirect from `a` to `b` and a row in the `wp-postmeta` table with `meta_key=_wp_old_slug` and `meta_value` with the old slug. Is this supposed to work for pages as well? I think I've had a setup where this works before but now I'm not sure anymore. Is there a default redirect system like this that would also work when changing parents of a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages are, from the underlying engine's point of view, posts with a `post_type` of `page`. So you should ideally see the same redirects.

However, you may find a plugin like [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) solves your issue more completely.